# I try to make simple app that ask user to fill info and then display it in html page

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is the `app.py` file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

#create application object
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.db'

#create the sqlalchemy object0
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#import db schema
from models import *

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/pro', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['username'] or not request.form['age'] or not request.form['Email']:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')

        #Check if the email address is valid. If not, raise an error
        elif not is_email_address_valid(request.form['email']):
            flash('Please enter a valid email address', 'error')

        else:
            # The data is valid. So create a new 'tabel' object
            # to save to the database
            tabel = BlogPost(request.form['name'],
                             request.form['age'],
                             request.form['Email'])

            #Add it to the SQLAlchemy session and commit it to
            #save it to the database
            db.session.add(tabel)
            db.session.commit()

            #Flash a success message
            flash('Comment was successfully submitted')

        return redirect(url_for('profile.html'))

  #start the server with the run() method
  if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

`models.py`

```
#import data base name db
from app import db

# define the tabel name
__ tablename__ = "BlogPost"

class BlogPost(db.Model):    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username= db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    age= db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    Email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, username, age, Email):
        self.username = username
        self.age = age
        self.Email= Email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<username{}'.format(self.username)
```

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link>
  <href="/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <div class="header">
       <h3 class="text-muted">Please fill the information</h3>
     </div>
     </hr>

     {%- for category, message in get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
       <div class="alert alert-danger">
       {{ message }}
        </div>
      {%- endfor %}

      <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ request.path }}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="comment" class="col-lg-2 control-label">age</label>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="age">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`profile.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask Profile</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome to profile!</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Click <a href="/logout">here</a> to logout.</p>
        <br><br>
        <h3>Posts:</h3>
        {% for tabel in BlogPost %}
        <strong>Name:</strong> {{ tabel.username }} <br>
        <strong>age:</strong> {{ tabel.age}} <br>
        <strong>Email:</strong> {{ tabel.Email}} <br>
        <br>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
        {{ message }}
        {% endfor %}
       </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `index.html` when I press submit and it doesn't go through the validatiion and  it doesn't direct to profile.html I got an error

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

what am I doing wrong and How can I fix it?

Comment: Still couldn't Run It Any help?????

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting the form to your `index` endpoint which doesn't accept POST requests. I think what you really mean to do is submit the form to your `new` endpoint. To do that, change

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ request.path }}" method="post">
```

to

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url_for('new') }}" method="post">
```

Comment: if request.method == 'POST':
NameError: global name 'request' is not defined

Comment: Thanx, But it doesn't fix the problem now I got an error , NameError NameError: global name 'request' is not defined                     if request.method == 'POST': NameError: global name 'request' is not defined –  Pegasuss just now

Comment: @Pegasuss: then *import* that name. `from flask import request`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanx I forgot that Now I have another error Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: @dim Can you help me with this??? I know that it shouldn't be hard to solve But can't get the solution

Comment: You You're probably getting a `KeyError` because the form field is named `email` but you're checking for `request.form['Email'].